# Trying to scrape a webpage with multiple data tables, however only the first table is being extracted?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am trying to extract data from basketball players off of Basketball-Reference for a project I am working on. On B-R, a player page has multiple tables of data and I want to grab all of it. However, when I try to grab the tables from the page, it only gives me the first instance of a table tag, i.e only the first table.

I have searched through the html and found that outside the first instance of the table tag, all the table tags are under a comment block. When I parse their parent tag and try and search for the child tag that contains the table information, it returns nothing. [Here is a link to an example page](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html), and here is my code:

```
url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html'
get = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(get.text, 'html.parser')

per_36 = soup.find(id='all_per_minute')
table = per_36.find('table')
```

This returns nothing, however, if I were to instead look for the first table, it would return the contents. I don't understand what is going on, but I think it may have something to do with those comment blocks?

Comment: Looks like the page loads data dynamically using jscript. Search around for Selenium (or other alternatives).

Comment: Also, find only returns first match whereas find_all returns all matches. And id is usually,  not always, unique so would result in one match. Haven't looked to see if there are nested tables however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape comments via BeautifulSoup, you could use this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html'
get = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(get.text, 'html.parser')

pl = soup.select_one('#all_per_minute .placeholder')
comments = pl.find_next(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

soup = BeautifulSoup(comments, 'html.parser')

rows = []
for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    rows.append([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td, th')])

for row in rows:
    print(''.join('{: ^7}'.format(td) for td in row))
```

Prints:

```
Season   Age    Tm     Lg     Pos     G     GS     MP     FG     FGA    FG%    3P     3PA    3P%    2P     2PA    2P%    FT     FTA    FT%    ORB    DRB    TRB    AST    STL    BLK    TOV    PF     PTS  
2003-04  19     CLE    NBA    SG     79     79    3122    7.2   17.2   .417    0.7    2.5   .290    6.4   14.7   .438    4.0    5.3   .754    1.1    3.8    5.0    5.4    1.5    0.7    3.1    1.7   19.1  
2004-05  20     CLE    NBA    SF     80     80    3388    8.4   17.9   .472    1.1    3.3   .351    7.3   14.6   .499    5.1    6.8   .750    1.2    5.1    6.2    6.1    1.9    0.6    2.8    1.6   23.1  
2005-06  21     CLE    NBA    SF     79     79    3361    9.4   19.5   .480    1.4    4.1   .335    8.0   15.5   .518    6.4    8.7   .738    0.8    5.2    6.0    5.6    1.3    0.7    2.8    1.9   26.5  
2006-07  22     CLE    NBA    SF     78     78    3190    8.7   18.3   .476    1.1    3.5   .319    7.6   14.8   .513    5.5    7.9   .698    0.9    5.0    5.9    5.3    1.4    0.6    2.8    1.9   24.1  
2007-08  23     CLE    NBA    SF     75     74    3027    9.4   19.5   .484    1.3    4.3   .315    8.1   15.3   .531    6.5    9.2   .712    1.6    5.5    7.0    6.4    1.6    1.0    3.0    2.0   26.8  
2008-09  24     CLE    NBA    SF     81     81    3054    9.3   19.0   .489    1.6    4.5   .344    7.7   14.5   .535    7.0    9.0   .780    1.2    6.0    7.2    6.9    1.6    1.1    2.8    1.6   27.2  
2009-10  25     CLE    NBA    SF     76     76    2966    9.3   18.5   .503    1.6    4.7   .333    7.8   13.8   .560    7.2    9.4   .767    0.9    5.9    6.7    7.9    1.5    0.9    3.2    1.4   27.4  
2010-11  26     MIA    NBA    SF     79     79    3063    8.9   17.5   .510    1.1    3.3   .330    7.8   14.2   .552    5.9    7.8   .759    0.9    6.0    6.9    6.5    1.5    0.6    3.3    1.9   24.8  
2011-12  27     MIA    NBA    SF     62     62    2326    9.6   18.1   .531    0.8    2.3   .362    8.8   15.8   .556    6.0    7.8   .771    1.5    6.2    7.6    6.0    1.8    0.8    3.3    1.5   26.0  

...and so on.
```